# Access hardware / device info through vscode API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to access hardware infos from within a vscode extension?

The macbook pro touchbar is slightly larger for the 15" model compared to the 13" one and I'd like to show different content for the respective devices.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code extensions run in a node environment. You can use a shell script or node library to access the system information, but keep in mind that using native dependencies [requires some extra work](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/658)